# PDO Error on insert

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I know that the source of my problem must be somewhere in my statement, but I just can't find it. Maybe you have a better eye than me right now.

I get the following error while trying to insert a row in my table:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Here is my insert function:

```
private function _insert()
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO shows (
            thetvdb_id,
            name,
            imdb_id,
            language,
            overview,
            genre,
            lastupdated,
            status
            )' .
            ' VALUES (
            :thetvdb_id,
            :name,
            :imdb_id,
            :language,
            :overview,
            :genre,
            :lastupdated,
            :status
            )';
            $abfrage = self::$db->prepare($sql);
            $abfrage->execute($this->toArray(false));
            //Setze die ID auf den von der DB generierten Wert
            $this->id = self::$db->lastInsertId();
    }
```

And here a sample object I'm passing:

```
object(Show)#201 (9) {
  ["id":"Show":private]=>
  int(0)
  ["thetvdb_id":"Show":private]=>
  string(5) "74875"
  ["name":"Show":private]=>
  string(10) "The Closer"
  ["imdb_id":"Show":private]=>
  string(9) "tt0458253"
  ["language":"Show":private]=>
  string(2) "en"
  ["overview":"Show":private]=>
  string(358) "Deputy Police Chief Brenda Leigh Johnson (Kyra Sedgwick) is a police detective who transfers from Atlanta to Los Angeles to head up a special unit of the LAPD that handles sensitive, high-profile murder cases. Despite a tendency to step on people\'s toes, Johnson manages to convert even her strongest adversaries with her unique ability to get to the truth."
  ["genre":"Show":private]=>
  string(21) "|Crime|Drama|Mystery|"
  ["lastupdated":"Show":private]=>
  string(10) "1410004625"
  ["status":"Show":private]=>
  string(5) "Ended"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 8 vars in sql query:

```
        :thetvdb_id,
        :name,
        :imdb_id,
        :language,
        :overview,
        :genre,
        :lastupdated,
        :status
```

And 9 vars in your array/object.

Comment: Yes I know. The `id` should be set via `autoincrement` in the table if it is an insert instead of an update, but it's part of the object. I've always done it like that without problems. That's what confuses me so much.

Answer (score 1):

you're sending in 9 parameters ( the extra is ID ) and that's not allowed, check out: 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

specifically:

> input_parameters .... **You cannot bind more values than specified;** if
>   more keys exist in input_parameters than in the SQL specified in the
>   PDO::prepare(), then the statement will fail and an error is emitted.